# Unmarshalling a List into a JavaFX SimpleListProperty

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got a nested object hierarchy which looks like this:

`Profile`: contains a `List<Category>`

`Category` contains a `List<Script>`. It is exposed via a JavaFX SimpleListProperty, so that it can be bound to via JavaFX's data binding.

`Script` contains nothing but simple values.

I'm just using JAXB to marshall and unmarshall POJOs. There are no databases or XML schemas involved.

Marshalling a `Profile` value works fine, and generates valid XML.  However, unmarshalling the same XML file later, results in each `Category` containing an empty `List<Script>`. This appears to be due to the fact that Category stores the `List<Script>` by using a JavaFX bindable property.

Is there a way to make JAXB properly deserialize into a SimpleListProperty that contains a custom object?

Here's a minimal sample that demonstrates the same issue.

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {                
        Script script1 = new Script();
        script1.name = "Script 1";
        script1.otherData = "Script 1's data";

        Script script2 = new Script();
        script2.name = "Script 2";
        script2.otherData = "Script 2's data";

        ArrayList<Script> scriptList = new ArrayList<Script>();
        scriptList.add(script1);
        scriptList.add(script2);

        Category category1 = new Category();
        category1.name = "Category 1";           
        category1.setCategoryScripts(scriptList);        

        Category category2 = new Category();
        category2.name = "Category 2";
        category2.setCategoryScripts(scriptList);        

        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.name = "Profile 1";
        profile.categories.add(category1);
        profile.categories.add(category2);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Profile.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
        m.marshal(profile, xml);

        System.out.println(xml.toString());

        Profile deserializedProfile = (Profile)context
                .createUnmarshaller()
                .unmarshal(new StringReader(xml.toString()));                

        System.out.println("Profile: " + deserializedProfile.name);
        for(Category cat : deserializedProfile.categories)
        {
            System.out.println("Category: " + cat.name);
            System.out.println("Scripts:");
            for(Script s : cat.getCategoryScripts())
            {
                System.out.printf("\nName: %s, Data: %s", s.name, s.otherData);
            }
        }
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class Profile
{
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement
    ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}

@XmlRootElement
class Category
{
    @XmlElement
    String name;

    ListProperty<Script> categoryScripts = new SimpleListProperty<Script>();
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement
    public final List<Script> getCategoryScripts() { return categoryScripts.get(); }
    public final void setCategoryScripts(List<Script> value) { categoryScripts.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(value)); }
    public ListProperty<Script> categoryScriptProperty() { return categoryScripts; }            
}

@XmlRootElement
class Script
{
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    @XmlElement
    String otherData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of StackOverflow is *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable* questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

When creating such test code, I did this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Categories.class);

        Categories categoriesIn = new Categories();
        categoriesIn.scripts.add(new Script("Hello"));
        categoriesIn.scripts.add(new Script("World"));

        StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
        jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(categoriesIn, xml);

        System.out.println(xml.toString());

        Categories categoriesOut = (Categories)jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
        System.out.println(categoriesOut.scripts.size() + " scripts:");
        for (Script script : categoriesOut.scripts)
            System.out.println("  " + script.name);
    }
}
@XmlRootElement
class Categories {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Scripts")
    @XmlElement(name = "Script")
    List<Script> scripts = new ArrayList<>();
}
class Script {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;
    Script() {}
    Script(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Running it produced:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><categories><Scripts><Script><name>Hello</name></Script><Script><name>World</name></Script></Scripts></categories>
2 scripts:
  Hello
  World
```

It seems to work fine, on Java 8 at least.

Try it out. If it doesn't work, then you might need to upgrade Java to a newer version. If it works, you might use it as a baseline to see what might be different in your code.

Comment: Noted. I'll rework the question to have a more minimal, runnable sample that demonstrates the issue in question.
~EDIT~ Done. Writing the sample seems to have shed a little more light on the issue--it seems to be related to the use of SimpleListProperty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into a weirdness of JAXB. Notice that you don't have an `addCategoryScript` method. So how is JAXB going to add `Script` objects to the list?

It could create a list of it's own, then give it to you with `setCategoryScripts`, but how would it know what kind of list to create?

It solves that dilemma by calling `getCategoryScripts` to get the initial (empty) list, and then add elements to it.

But then what happens if you returned a copy of the internal list?
Ah Ha! Call `setCategoryScripts` when the list is complete.

This means that it'll call `setCategoryScripts` with the list returned by `getCategoryScripts`.

I has an implementation that needed some special handling, so what I did was:

```
public List<MyObj> getMyList() {
    return this.myList;
}
public void setMyList(List<MyObj> myList) {
    this.myList.clear();
    for (MyObj o : myList)
        this.myList.add(handle(o));
}
```

But oops. The call to `clear` actually cleared the incoming `objList` parameter, and I ended up with nothing.

My solution was to copy the parameter list before proceeding.