# saving data in xml format

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jaxb

In my data storage application, I use `ObservableList <MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();` where `MainData` is a class where all variables and collections for working with data are stored. My task is to save all this data in XML format. I know that `ObservableList` needs wrapping to save everything, I did it, here is my code

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mainData")
public class DataListWrapper {

    private List<MainData> mainData;

    @XmlElement(name = "mainData")
    public List<MainData> getMainData() {
        return mainData;
    }

    public void setMainData(List<MainData> mainData) {
        this.mainData = mainData;
    }
}
```

This code works, but it only saves to me the variables that are in `MainData`, and I also have the `ListProperty` collections there, how can I fix this? If you need me to provide the entire `MainData` class I will do it.

```
How do I do this for the `ListProperty` type?

    public class ListPropertyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, ListProperty> {

        @Override
        public ListProperty unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return ListProperty.parse(v); //I do not know what to write here
        }

        @Override
        public String marshal(ListProperty v) throws Exception {
            return v.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `XmlRootElement` is used with JAXB. So are you using JAXB? `FXCollections` is used with JavaFX. So are you using JavaFX?

Comment: @Abra Yes i am using JAXB

Comment: @Abra My application is written in JavaFX, and for saving to XML I use JAXB

Comment: Return an object that ***can*** be marshalled instead of `String`...

Comment: @fabian I do not understand how to do it

Comment: Basically you want to convert a bunch of `MainData` objects to XML using JAXB. In the JAXB terminology this is known as _marshalling_. So start by posting the code for your `MainData` class.

Comment: @Abra If I understood correctly, then I have already done everything, the problem is only with unmarshaling, I do not know how to return SimpleListProperty (ListProperty) to the Java object

Comment: So you have XML of a marshaled object and you want to unmarshal it to get a [ListProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ListProperty.html) object, correct? I found two _Stack Overflow_ questions that may be relevant. [Unmarshalling a List into a JavaFX SimpleListProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705179/unmarshalling-a-list-into-a-javafx-simplelistproperty) and [Unmarshal List to Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590229/unmarshal-list-to-types)